# IMultiLanguage2::ConvertStringFromUnicode - how to avoid compound prefix?

Tags: winapi, unicode, character-encoding, utf-16

I am using IMultilanguage2::ConvertStringFromUnicode to convert from UTF-16. For some languages (Japanese, Chinese, Korean), I am getting an escape sequence (e.g. `0x1B, 0x24, 0x29, 0x43` for codepage 50225 (ISO-2022 Korean)). WideCharToMultiByte exhibits the same behavior.

I am building a MIME message, so the encoding is specified in the header itself and the escape prefix is displayed as-is.

Is there a way to convert without the prefix?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the actual problem? If that is what the API is returning, then that is what your input Unicode string actually converts to in ISO-2022 Korean.  You have to specify `charset=iso-2022-kr` in the MIME `Content-Type` header.

Comment: The problem is that prefix is not needed. If I use Outlook (IConverterSession) to create the MIME file, the value of the MIME header (To) is exactly like mine minus the 4 bytes prefix. Both Outlook and my code specify "iso-2022-kr" in the header's value. I can remove the prefix (the list of possible prefixes can be found, for example, at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/ICU/ICU-491.11.3/icuSources/common/ucnv_ct.c), but I would prefer IMultiLanguage to do the job.

Comment: Whether it is *needed* or not, it is still *valid* per ISO 2022.  If Outlook cannot handle it correctly then Outlook is broken.

Comment: Remy, nobody is saying that it is invalid. All I am saying is that it is not needed since the charset is explicitly specified. Whether Outlook is broken or not is also irrelevant since I can't really fix the "problem" in Outlook and distribute the fix to all billion or so Outlook users.

Comment: `IMultiLanguage` and `WideCharToMultiByte()` have no clue how you are going to use their output, so they have to include the prefix so a decoder would know what charset to use.  When you put the data into a MIME header/body, you will just have to strip off the prefix manually if you are going to explicitly specify `iso-2022-kr` as the MIME data's charset.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see a problem here.  That is a valid byte sequence in [ISO 2022](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022):

> Escape sequences to designate character sets take the form **ESC *I* [*I...*] *F***, where there are one or more intermediate *I* bytes from the range 0x20–0x2F, and a final *F* byte from the range 0x40–0x7F. (The range 0x30–0x3F is reserved for private-use *F* bytes.) The *I* bytes identify the type of character set and the working set it is to be designated to, while the *F* byte identifies the character set itself.
> ...
> Code: ESC $ ) *F*
> Hex: 1B 24 29 *F*
> Abbr: G1DM4
> Name: G1-designate multibyte 94-set F
> Effect: selects a 94n-character set to be used for G1.

As *F* is 0x43 (C), this byte sequence tells a decoder to switch to ISO-2022-KR:

> Character encodings using ISO/IEC 2022 mechanism include:
> ...
> ISO-2022-KR. An encoding for Korean.
> **ESC $ ) C** to switch to [**KS X 1001-1992**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KSX1001), previously named KS C 5601-1987 (2 bytes per character) [*designated to G1*]

In this case, you have to specify `iso-2022-kr` as the charset in a MIME `Content-Type` or [RFC2047](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047)-encoded header.  But an ISO 2022 decoder still has to be able to switch charsets dynamically while decoding, so it is valid for the data to include an intial switch sequence to the Korean charset.

> Is there a way to convert without the prefix?

Not with `IMultiLanguage2` and `WideCharToMultiByte()`, no.  They have no clue how you are going to use their output, so it makes sense why they include an initial switch sequence to the Korean charset - so a decoder without access to charset info from MIME (or other source) would still know what charset to use initially.

When you put the data into a MIME message, you will have to manually strip off the charset switch sequence when you set the MIME charset to `iso-2022-kr`.  If you do not want to strip it manually, you will have to find (or write) a Unicode encoder that does not output that initial switch sequence.

Answer (score 1):

That was a red herring - turned out the escape sequence *is* necessary. The problem was with my code that was trimming the names and addresses using Trim() Delphi function, which trims all characters less than or equal to space (0x20); that includes the escape character (0x1B).

Switching to my own trimming function that removes only spaces fixed the problem.